# Mercurial 1.5 pager on Windows

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to set the pager used for Mercurial but the output is empty, even if I specify the command in the `[pager]` section or as the `PAGER` environment variable.

I noticed that the command provided is launched with `cmd.exe`. Is this the cause of empty output, and if yes, what is the right syntax?

Environment: Mercurial 1.5, Mercurial 1.4.3

hgrc:

```
[extensions]
pager =

[pager]
pager = d:\tools\less\less.exe
```

Sample command lines (from Process Explorer):

```
hg diff
c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "d:\tools\less\less.exe 2> NUL:"
d:\tools\less\less.exe
```

**UPDATE**

In pager.py, by replacing:

```
sys.stderr = sys.stdout = util.popen(p, "wb")
```

with

```
sys.stderr = sys.stdout = subprocess.Popen(p, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, shell=False).stdin
```

I managed to obtain the desired output for the hg status and diff.

BUT, I'm sure it's wrong (or at least incomplete), and I have no control over the pager app (less.exe): the output is shown in the cmd.exe window, I can see the less prompt (:) but any further input is fed into cmd.exe. It seems that the pager app is still active in the background: after typing exit in the cmd.exe window, I have control over the pager app,
and I can terminate it normally.

Also, it makes no difference what I'm choosing as a pager app (more is behaving the same).

**UPDATE 2**

[**Issue1677 - [PATCH] pager for "hg help" output on windows**](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1677)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the pager extension to use a temporary file for storing the commands output, the resulting extension can be found on [CodePlex](http://tpager.codeplex.com/) and [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/alexandrul/tpager/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the [pager extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PagerExtension) in your `~/.hgrc` or `mercurial.ini` file?

```
  [extensions]
  pager =
```

It's came with your mercurial installation, but you still need to enable it.

Comment: Already did that, when it's not enabled the output is the expected one, when it's enabled there is no output.

Comment: Hrm, what do you see when you run with `--debug`?

Comment: the behavior is the same: no output