# Mercurial (TortoiseHG) command-line on Windows does not respond to pager environment variables (and fails to use a pager at all)

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, pager, less-unix

When I run commands such as `hg log`, I expect to see the output in a pager. I have configured my repository `.hg\hgrc` to use `less`:

```
...
[pager]
pager = C:\path\to\bin\less.exe
...
```

I have confirmed that `less` is correctly installed, as I am able to run it.
I have also confirmed with `hg config --debug` that this environment setting is correctly registered:

```
...
C:\path\to\repo/.hg/hgrc:23: pager.pager=C:\path\to\bin\less.exe
...
```

However, the output is instead dumped into terminal. This is a major nuisance, especially with `hg log` since the project I am working on has history dating back to 2001. Removing the configuration settings does **not** cause output to go through `more`, which according to [Mercurial documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/pager) should be the default Windows pager. (and yes, I have checked that `more` is installed)

> If no pager is set in the user or repository configuration, Mercurial uses the environment variable $PAGER. If $PAGER is not set, pager.pager from the default or system configuration is used. If none of these are set, a default pager will be used, typically 'less' on Unix and 'more' on Windows.

Is it a known issue that Mercurial pager support on Windows is currently broken? If not, what steps can I take to make Mercurial recognize and use a pager? At this point I don't even care if it uses `less` as long as the output is sent to any pager.

**Environment**: Mercurial version 6.3.2 (*installed with TortoiseHG*) on Windows 11.
I have attempted to run hg commands through Command Prompt, Powershell, and Git Bash; none of them correctly use the pager configuration (or any other pager, e.g. `more`).

**EDIT:** in response to a comment below, here is the full output of `hg --version --verbose`:

```
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 6.3.2)
(see https://mercurial-scm.org for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2023 Olivia Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Enabled extensions:
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378573/mercurial-1-5-pager-on-windows) does not resolve my issue as it uses the PagerExtension, which is outdated and unnecessary as of current Mercurial version. I have also tried the steps here to use the PagerExtension, to no avail.

Comment: Just to double check, is `C:\path\to\bin\less.exe` definitely correct? If you paste that string exactly into a command prompt, it will work?

Comment: Yes, it is. Pasting the exact path successfully runs `less`.

Comment: Other Windows paths I have in my hgrc files are within double quotes, seems worth a shot.

Comment: Changed `pager = C:\path\to\bin\less.exe` to `pager = "C:\path\to\bin\less.exe"` and closed+reopened Powershell. Still no luck.

Comment: Do you have *pure* Mercurial or, maybe, THG?

Comment: Oh... If THG is TortoiseHG then yes, I installed THG. Does THG come with a "non-standard" version of Mercurial? I've posted `hg --version --verbose` in the question description, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseHG is slightly different than pure Mercurial in Windows, not due to code-changes, but (as it was discovered during last researches) due to py2exe limitations.
Pager support is one of such things: if you'll run `hg version --debug` you'll see warning about it

```
> hg version --debug
pager is unavailable with py2exe packaging
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 6.3.2)
(see https://mercurial-scm.org for more information)
...
```

Workarounds

- Use pure Mercurial in parallel with THG - install and put HG path in PATH after THG's
- Because I'm lazy (as declared) I use `hg log | bat -p -l log --pager "moar --no-linenumbers"` with best viewer and pager at a time and even still don't overload `hg log`in shell alias (use PowerShell history and expansion)